# What does "will never be" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I tried to guess what the full form of this sentence is, but I couldn't. Can anybody explain it for me, please? UBS will never be...too big to fail or...what?

"While UBS is one of Switzerland's two main lenders, Deutsche is Germany's only global bank. Although its misadventures in investment banking may have left it gasping for equity, the German lender is too big to fail in a way that **UBS will never be**. Deutsche Bank hasn't needed a bailout, but it's easy to see that with its deep ties at home, it could always get one."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/gadfly/articles/2017-05-16/hna-can-avoid-singapore-s-ubs-sour-grapes

Comment: ... too big to fail in the way that UBS will never be [too big to fail].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that (in the writer's opinion) there is no circumstance in which UBS could find itself the ONLY organisation capable of performing its function. While there is no other organisation in Germany that could take on Deutsche Bank's responsibilities if it were to fail, there is another bank in Switzerland that could service the market if UBS were to, say, have all of its computers wiped, or all of its money embezzled away, or similar.

**Too big to fail** refers to organisations that are so intertwined with a nation's economy that their bankruptcy would cause massive economic damage. The writer can see no way for UBS to ever be as integral to the Swiss economy as Deutsche is to the German.